# how to add fig caption for grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the top of the rmd file:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: no
    toc_depth: 3
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: true
```

and I have also set some chunk options:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE)
```

Here is my code

```
{r fig.cap="scatter plots for sepal length, sepal width and petal length" }
test = iris
a = ggplot(test) +
            geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color=Species))
b = ggplot(test) +
            geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, color=Species))
c = ggplot(test) +
            geom_point(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color=Species))

extract_legend = function(my_ggp) {
  step1 = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(my_ggp))
  step2 = which(sapply(step1$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  step3 = step1$grobs[[step2]]
  return(step3)
}

leg = extract_legend(a)
  
grid.arrange(a+theme(legend.position='hidden'), b+theme(legend.position='hidden'), 
             c+theme(legend.position='hidden'), leg,
             nrow=2, ncol=2)
```

However, this doesn't print the caption when knitting to pdf.

Is there a way to fix this?
I only want one caption for the three figures.
[image]

Comment: @RonakShah Yea sorry about that, it's just a function that I get from the internet.

Comment: @RonakShah is there any special settings you have in the yml header? I tried it in a new file and it still doesn't have the caption when using `grid.arrange`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to show this Rmd file works for me when I knit it in PDF.

````
---
title: "Temp"
output: pdf_document
--- 

```{r fig.cap="scatter plots for sepal length, sepal width and petal length" }
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
test = iris
a = ggplot(test) +
            geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color=Species))
b = ggplot(test) +
            geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, color=Species))
c = ggplot(test) +
            geom_point(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color=Species))

extract_legend = function(my_ggp) {
  step1 = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(my_ggp))
  step2 = which(sapply(step1$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  step3 = step1$grobs[[step2]]
  return(step3)
}

leg = extract_legend(a)
  
grid.arrange(a+theme(legend.position='hidden'), b+theme(legend.position='hidden'), 
             c+theme(legend.position='hidden'), leg,
             nrow=2, ncol=2)
````

[image]